# URL connection test - compilation error

Tags: java

I am new to Java, have searched on the net and this forum but unable to figure out why my code is not compiling? Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
//filename is TestHTTPConnection.java

class TestHTTPConnection {

public static void main (String[] args){

    String strUrl = "http://abc.com";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        URLConnection Conn = url.openConnection();
        Conn.connect();

        assertEquals(URLConnection.HTTP_OK, Conn.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error creating HTTP connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
}
```

Compilation error - complains about "URL", "URLConnection" and "IOException".

Comment: Generally speaking, posting the text of the actual error, not your summation of it, is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two things:

a package line:

```
package yourdomain.yourapp;
```

and a list of imports:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
```

Most java developers use an IDE which automates all of this (such as NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA, or Eclipse)

Comment: @Smit fixed extra import, thanks (was trash from a scratch implementation)

Comment: @Sudhanshu It's not related, I initially thought that package statements were required but after some quick searching that doesn't seem to be accurate.

Answer (score 4):

You need to import those classes / interfaces !

Answer (score 0):

If your not using an IDE (Eclipse , NetBeans etc.) then download one which will give you content assist and point out mistakes like this.

Comment: Thanks guys for your response. I am using notepad, I guess that's why it was unable to load / recognize the packages. I will leave this thread open for sometime, once I am able to fix the issue, I will close it. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: also if your new to Java you should try learning TDD and writing unit tests for the code your write. It's a great way to learn